# Infer schema using from_json of to_json value - Pyspark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have table like below by using to_json I am creating JSON structure and by call schema I am converting the string value to JSON value. But I am not getting the output as expected.

| A | B | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 222 | null |
| null | null | 333 |

I have written like below code

```py
df = spark.sql("select A as Test1, B as Test 2, C as Test from Table")

df_final = `df.select(F.to_json(struct(struct(df['Test1'], df['Test2']).alias('col1'), struct(df['Test']).alias('col2'))).alias('FinalData'))`

schema = `StructType([StructField('col1', StructType([ StructField('Test1',LongType(),True), StructField('Test2',LongType(),True)]),True),StructField('col2', StructType([StructField('Test2',LongType(),True)]),True)])`

df_final = `df_a.withColumn('FinalData',from_json('FinalData', schema))`
```

Expected Output:

| FinalData |
| --- |
| {"col1": {"Test1": 111, "Test2": 222}, "Col2": {"Test2": null}} |
| {"col1": {"Test1": null, "Test2": null}, "Col2": {"Test2": 333}} |

But actual Output is:

Expected Output:

| FinalData |
| --- |
| {"col1": {"Test1": 111, "Test2": 222}, "Col2": {"Test2": null}} |
| {"col1": {"Test1": null, "Test2": null}, "Col2": {"Test2": null}} |

Comment: Yes, I am using azure databricks